# combine 2-D arrays of unknown sizes to make one 3-D

Tags: numpy

I have a function, say peaksdetect(), that will generate a 2-D array of unknown number of rows; I will call it a few times, let's say 3 and I would like to make of these 3 arrays, one 3-D array. Here is my start but it is very complicated with a lot of if statements, so I want to make things simpler if possible:

```
import numpy as np

dim3 = 3   # the number of times peaksdetect() will be called
           # it is named dim3 because this number will determine 
           # the size of the third dimension of the result 3-D array

for num in range(dim3):
    data = peaksdetect(dataset[num])            # generates a 2-D array of unknown number of rows
    if num == 0:
        3Darray = np.zeros([dim3, data.shape])  # in fact the new dimension is in position 0
                                                # so dimensions 0 and 1 of "data" will be 
                                                # 1 and 2 respectively
    else:
        if data.shape[0] > 3Darray.shape[1]:
            "adjust 3Darray.shape[1] so that it equals data[0] by filling with zeroes"
            3Darray[num] = data
        else:
            "adjust data[0] so that it equals 3Darray.shape[1] by filling with zeroes"
            3Darray[num] = data
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are counting on having to resize your array, there is very likely not going to be much to be gained by preallocating it. It will probably be simpler to store your arrays in a list, then figure out the size of the array to hold them all, and dump the data into it:

```
data = []
for num in range(dim3):
    data.append(peaksdetect(dataset[num]))
shape = map(max, zip(*(j.shape for j in data)))
shape = (dim3,) + tuple(shape)
data_array = np.zeros(shape, dtype=data[0].dtype)
for j, d in enumerate(data):
    data_array[j, :d.shape[0], :d.shape[1]] = d
```

Comment: Works just great! In fact I don't know anything about the fundamentals in Python, for example what are lists.